# Elasticsearch aggregations filtering by top one result from each bucket

Tags: elasticsearch, immutability, aggregation

Given a dataset like this in a single index in Elasticsearch:

```
entityId | created    | status
---------+------------+-----------
1        | 2000/01/01 | draft
1        | 2001/01/02 | approved
2        | 2000/01/01 | draft
2        | 2000/01/02 | approved
2        | 2001/01/03 | rejected
3        | 2000/01/01 | draft
3        | 2001/01/03 | approved
```

I want to filter only on entities where the newest status is approved.

So I've been trying with aggregations and sub-aggregations and I've managed to get all entities out with only the newest status included like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "newest-event-query": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "entityId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "newest-event": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "created": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which should give a result like this:

```
entityId | created    | status
---------+------------+-----------
1        | 2001/01/02 | approved
2        | 2001/01/02 | rejected
3        | 2001/01/03 | approved
```

But I would like to filter that result further to only included the approved records (1, 3) and then finally be able to query on that result.

Adding an extra aggs to the top_hits aggs does not seem to work:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "newest-event-query": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "entityId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "newest-event": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "created": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "aggs": {
              "approved-only": {
                "filter": {
                  "term": {
                    "status": "approved"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

results in:

```
"error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[gupa9nwpQWmGa3JqFmF2NA][creations][0]: SearchParseException[[creations][0]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"size":0,"aggs":{"newest-event-query":{"terms":{"field":"entityId"},"aggs":{"newest-event":{"top_hits":{"size":1,"sort":[{"created":{"order":"desc"}}],"aggs":{"aproved-only":{"filter":{"term":{"status":"approved"}}}}}}}}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[creations][0]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [newest-event]: [aggs].]]; }{[gupa9nwpQWmGa3JqFmF2NA][events][0]: SearchParseException[[events][0]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"size":0,"aggs":{"newest-event-query":{"terms":{"field":"entityId"},"aggs":{"newest-event":{"top_hits":{"size":1,"sort":[{"created":{"order":"desc"}}],"aggs":{"aproved-only":{"filter":{"term":{"status":"approved"}}}}}}}}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[events][0]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [newest-event]: [aggs].]]; }{[gupa9nwpQWmGa3JqFmF2NA][creations][1]: SearchParseException[[creations][1]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"size":0,"aggs":{"newest-event-query":{"terms":{"field":"entityId"},"aggs":{"newest-event":{"top_hits":{"size":1,"sort":[{"created":{"order":"desc"}}],"aggs":{"aproved-only":{"filter":{"term":{"status":"approved"}}}}}}}}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[creations][1]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [newest-event]: [aggs].]]; }{[gupa9nwpQWmGa3JqFmF2NA][events][1]: SearchParseException[[events][1]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"size":0,"aggs":{"newest-event-query":{"terms":{"field":"entityId"},"aggs":{"newest-event":{"top_hits":{"size":1,"sort":[{"created":{"order":"desc"}}],"aggs":{"aproved-only":{"filter":{"term":{"status":"approved"}}}}}}}}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[events][1]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [newest-event]: [aggs].]]; }{[gupa9nwpQWmGa3JqFmF2NA][creations][2]: SearchParseException[[creations][2]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"size":0,"aggs":{"newest-event-query":{"terms":{"field":"entityId"},"aggs":{"newest-event":{"top_hits":{"size":1,"sort":[{"created":{"order":"desc"}}],"aggs":{"aproved-only":{"filter":{"term":{"status":"approved"}}}}}}}}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[creations][2]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [newest-event]: [aggs].]]; }{[gupa9nwpQWmGa3JqFmF2NA][events][2]: SearchParseException[[events][2]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"size":0,"aggs":{"newest-event-query":{"terms":{"field":"entityId"},"aggs":{"newest-event":{"top_hits":{"size":1,"sort":[{"created":{"order":"desc"}}],"aggs":{"aproved-only":{"filter":{"term":{"status":"approved"}}}}}}}}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[events][2]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [newest-event]: [aggs].]]; }{[gupa9nwpQWmGa3JqFmF2NA][creations][3]: SearchParseException[[creations][3]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"size":0,"aggs":{"newest-event-query":{"terms":{"field":"entityId"},"aggs":{"newest-event":{"top_hits":{"size":1,"sort":[{"created":{"order":"desc"}}],"aggs":{"aproved-only":{"filter":{"term":{"status":"approved"}}}}}}}}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[creations][3]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [newest-event]: [aggs].]]; }{[gupa9nwpQWmGa3JqFmF2NA][events][3]: SearchParseException[[events][3]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"size":0,"aggs":{"newest-event-query":{"terms":{"field":"entityId"},"aggs":{"newest-event":{"top_hits":{"size":1,"sort":[{"created":{"order":"desc"}}],"aggs":{"aproved-only":{"filter":{"term":{"status":"approved"}}}}}}}}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[events][3]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [newest-event]: [aggs].]]; }{[gupa9nwpQWmGa3JqFmF2NA][creations][4]: SearchParseException[[creations][4]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"size":0,"aggs":{"newest-event-query":{"terms":{"field":"entityId"},"aggs":{"newest-event":{"top_hits":{"size":1,"sort":[{"created":{"order":"desc"}}],"aggs":{"aproved-only":{"filter":{"term":{"status":"approved"}}}}}}}}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[creations][4]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [newest-event]: [aggs].]]; }{[gupa9nwpQWmGa3JqFmF2NA][events][4]: SearchParseException[[events][4]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"size":0,"aggs":{"newest-event-query":{"terms":{"field":"entityId"},"aggs":{"newest-event":{"top_hits":{"size":1,"sort":[{"created":{"order":"desc"}}],"aggs":{"aproved-only":{"filter":{"term":{"status":"approved"}}}}}}}}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[events][4]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [newest-event]: [aggs].]]; }]",
"status": 400
```

Any help appreciated.

**Edit:** Filtering on approved will not work, since events can go from approved and back to another status. I always need to filter by newest status. The point of this excercise is to create an immutable data structure - a single entity can go though a lot of stages but we should always only query by the latest one.

**Edit 2:** To find a solution I've also looked at the parent-child structure, and while close it still have some limitations, like the has_parent or has_child needs to have a fixed "id". Another obvious and performant solution is to simple mark the newest item on write - eg. with a boolean, but I want atomicity and resetting that boolean on one document and setting it on the new one is not an atomic operation.

Comment: Why can't you just do a filtered query for approved?  Is there some status that comes after approved?

Comment: why can't you add filtered query, so aggregation were applied on filtered resulset?

Comment: Added further explaination - does it manke sense?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and [bucket selector aggreation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html).
Under a term I have created a bucket of most recent entry using max aggregation on created date field and also a bucket of created date where status is approved". Using bucket selector I have kept the terms where latest date and latest approve date is same

```
Entity: 1                                        --> using terms aggregation
     "Latest created date":"2001-01-02"          --> using max aggregation
     "Latest approved doc":                      --> using filter aggregation
            "Latest approved date":"2000-01-01"  --> Using max aggregation
     "Bucket where Latest created date==Latest approved doc>Latest approved date" 
                                                 --> using bucket selector aggregation
```

Mapping

```
{
  "index90" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "created" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "[yyyy-MM-dd]"
        },
        "entityId" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "status" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index90",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "xZsmY3EBdTQt60iNXDQB",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "entityId" : 1,
          "created" : "2000-01-01",
          "status" : "draft"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index90",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "xpsmY3EBdTQt60iNojQc",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "entityId" : 1,
          "created" : "2001-01-02",
          "status" : "approved"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index90",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "x5smY3EBdTQt60iN7DQc",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "entityId" : 2,
          "created" : "2000-01-01",
          "status" : "draft"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index90",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "yJsnY3EBdTQt60iNAzT7",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "entityId" : 2,
          "created" : "2000-01-02",
          "status" : "approved"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index90",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "yZsnY3EBdTQt60iNIjQY",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "entityId" : 2,
          "created" : "2000-01-03",
          "status" : "rejected"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Query:

```
{
 "aggs": {
   "entitites": {
     "terms": {
       "field": "entityId",
       "size": 10
     },
     "aggs": {
       "latest_entry": {
         "max": {
           "field": "created"
         }
       },
       "latest_approved_entry":{
         "filter": {
           "term": {
             "status.keyword": "approved"
           }
         },
         "aggs": {
           "approved_date": {
             "max": {
               "field": "created"
             }
           }
         }
       },
       "select_bucket_with":{
         "bucket_selector": {
           "buckets_path": {
             "latest_entry":"latest_entry",
             "latest_approved_entry":"latest_approved_entry>approved_date"
           },
           "script": "if(params['latest_entry']==params['latest_approved_entry']) return true;"
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Result:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "entitites" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 1,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "latest_entry" : {
            "value" : 9.783936E11,
            "value_as_string" : "2001-01-02"
          },
          "latest_approved_entry" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "approved_date" : {
              "value" : 9.783936E11,
              "value_as_string" : "2001-01-02"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```